# SQL Server | Finding out count and category

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table A

```
Owner   row_no   category
-------------------------
A        1         U
B        1         T
B        2         T
C        1         U
C        2         T
C        3         U
C        4         U
```

I'm looking for a solution that stores values into other table which should retrieve

1. row_no as 1 if the value is 1 and should return max(row_no)-1 if the value isn't 1.
2. category should be either T or U or both based on whether an owner has opted for only T or U or both in TABLE A.

Expected table output should be something like below.

```
Owner   row_no   category
---------------------------
A        1         U
B        1         T
C        3        Both
```

I tried using the below approach which turns out to be an error.

```
SELECT * 
INTO B 
FROM A
WHERE ROW_NO LIKE CASE
                     WHEN ROW_NO = 1 THEN ROW_NO
                                     ELSE MAX(ROW_NO) - 1
                  END
```

Haven't figured out yet on retrieving the category!

Could you please help with correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is not completely clear to me.  In particular, I assume here that your logic for reporting the `row_no` is to return 1 when the max value for an owner is 1, otherwise to return that max value minus 1.

We can try doing a simple aggregation query here to generate what you want.

```
SELECT
    Owner,
    CASE WHEN MAX(row_no) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(row_no) - 1 END AS row_no,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT category) > 1 THEN 'Both' ELSE MAX(category) END AS category
FROM tableA
GROUP BY
    Owner;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM(VALUES ('A',1,'U'),
                ('B',1,'T'),
                ('B',2,'T'),
                ('C',1,'U'),
                ('C',2,'T'),
                ('C',3,'U'),
                ('C',4,'U')) V([Owner], Row_no, Category))
SELECT [Owner],
       ISNULL(NULLIF(MAX(Row_no) - 1,0),1) AS Row_no,
       CASE WHEN MIN(Category) = MAX(Category) THEN MAX(Category) ELSE 'Both' END AS Category --Assumes Category cannot have a value of NULL
FROM VTE
GROUP BY [Owner];
```